# SQL Server LaunchPad "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" + No Log in ExtensibilityLog

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, r

I'm trying to start LaunchPad service but it fails to start with:

> Error 1053: "The service did not respond in a timely fashion"

I've been reading this was common in RC versions but I'm running SQL Server 2016 SP1 + CU3.

I've tried to add the *SQLRUserGroup* to the *LogOnLocally* user right assignment. The service still not run.

Also, there is no log in folder `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL13.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Log\ExtensibilityLog`

I've tried to change security of log folder including the `NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad` and the `SQLRUserGroup` entries.

Answer (score 4):

I has this issue, this tutorial did the trick for me.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4558/sql-server-launchpad-service-cannot-be-started/

Should be noted an easy work around for me was just to change the account to NETWORK SERVICE in config manager, if you're not fussed about using a dedicated account for security reasons it will likely work for you also.

Comment: I'd to *also* add NT Service\MSSQLLaunchpad to Administrator group, and then I did started the service (and then the installation continued. I had the issue even in the installation process)

Answer (score 0):

If Launchpad does not start up and the service account is saying locked out in Event viewers follow these steps.

1. Go to Edit Users and Groups
2. Click on Users
3. Go through each users MSSQLSERVER00 T0  MSSQLSERVER20 (one of these will be locked out). unlock it and try to launchpad Should work.

Answer (score 0):

*[Dan](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/131828/dan) (question author):*

It was fixed reinstalling SP1. We reproduced the issue by following these steps:

- Install SQL 2016
- Update it with SP1
- Add R Services using the installation (no SP1)

---

[Dave Mason](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/37395/dave-mason): On SQL Server 2017, reinstalling the latest CU (after installing ML services) worked for me.