# SQL Server 2008 R2 - The request failed or the service did not respond in timely fashion

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server failed to start and throwing error - "The request failed or the service did not respond in timely fashion. Consult the event log or other applicable error logs for details."

[image: error message]

I have tried the solution given [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182455/sql-server-launchpad-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion-no-log)

I have tried multiple solutions but neither have worked\

1. Tried to built-in account to Local System, Local Service and Network service.
2. Reinstalled the SQL Server.
3. Disabled the VIA in SQL Server network configuration.

Any solution to solve my problem?

Window Error Log:

1. SQL Server could not spawn FRunCM thread. Check the SQL Server error log and the Windows event logs for information about possible related problems.
2. Could not start the network library because of an internal error in the network library. To determine the cause, review the errors immediately preceding this one in the error log.
3. TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x1. Reason: Initialization failed with an infrastructure error. Check for previous errors. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.
4. TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

SQL Server error log:

> The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL connection. It returned the following error: 0x80090331. Check certificates to make sure they are valid.
>
> Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.
>
> Error: 17182, Severity: 16, State: 1.TDSSNIClient initialization failed with error 0x80090331, status code 0x80. Reason: Unable to initialize SSL support. The client and server cannot communicate, because they do not possess a common algorithm.

Comment: so what does your Windows log say?

Comment: What is in SQL Server error log?

Comment: @GeorgeK I have added window error log in question. thanks

Comment: @sepupic this what i found on sql server error log:   The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL connection. It returned the following error: 0x80090331. Check certificates to make sure they are valid.

Comment: @sepupic Unable to initialize SSL encryption because a valid certificate could not be found, and it is not possible to create a self-signed certificate.

Comment: @Jagz W Your server is configured to use encryption but it seems that you didn't provide the certificate. Was it supposed to use encryption or it was done by mistake? Of course changing service account cannot resolve this issue, you should provide the certificate or reconfigure the server to not to use encryption

Comment: @sepupic the error is resolved by updating required SSL certificates. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @John Eisbrener Ok, I posted it as the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the server cannot start, the first thing to consult is `SQL Server error log`.
There can be different reasons, for example, banally the port assigned is occupied. But in OP case it was

> The server could not load the certificate it needs to initiate an SSL
>   connection

The error message itself suggested what to do:

> Check certificates to make sure they are valid

Another option in this case was to remove encryption at all if it was configured by mistake

Answer (score 0):

The error is resolved by updating required SSL certificates.