# SQL Server was unable to communicate with the LaunchPad service

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssms

I have run the below code:

```
execute sp_configure 'external scripts enabled';
```

and it is giving me the output as:

```
name                    minimum maximum config_value    run_value
external scripts enabled    0    1       1              1
```

I have also started the launchpad services, still when I am running the below code:

```
exec sp_execute_external_script @language =N'R',   
@script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',  
@input_data_1 =N'select 1+1 as SUMOutput'  
with result sets (([SUM Output] int not null));  
go
```

It is throwing the error:

> Msg 39011, Level 16, State 1, Line 7 SQL Server was unable to
>   communicate with the LaunchPad service. Please verify the
>   configuration of the service.   Msg 11536, Level 16, State 1, Line 7
>   EXECUTE statement failed because its WITH RESULT SETS clause specified
>   1 result set(s), but the statement only sent 0 result set(s) at run
>   time.

I have SQL Server 2016 editon and the SQL Server Management Studio is 2017.
i have the following snippet of my services.
[image: Services running]

Comment: FWIW, I only get that error when the Launch Pad service (MSSQLLaunchpad) is stopped. If you are 100% sure that the service is running, it might be a config issue (check the registry) or check the permissions of the service account for the MSSQLSERVER service (or MSSQL$InstanceName).

Comment: Can you run a simple "Hello World" without error? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/advanced-analytics/tutorials/rtsql-using-r-code-in-transact-sql-quickstart?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: no i am not able to run a simple hello world program,still giving the same error."SQL Server was unable to communicate with the LaunchPad service. Please verify the configuration of the service."

Comment: @SolomonRutzky: Can you please help me as to how to check the permissions of the service account for the MSSQLSERVER service?Or config settings?

Comment: @sparklzrocks - it may not get you any further in finding a solution, but I'd suggest reading up on this question/answer - [Problem getting SQL Server 2016 R Services (In-Database) working](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/154637/60085)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and I solved it by installing the Service Pack on top of the media installed R.

I think it is a related to install an old version of LaunchPad on an already updated SQL Server.

As per this Q&A

[SQL Server LaunchPad "The service did not respond in a timely fashion" + No Log in ExtensibilityLog](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/182455/sql-server-launchpad-the-service-did-not-respond-in-a-timely-fashion-no-log?rq=1)

**My timeline.**

- My sql install was a semi-updated SP1.
- My media was a stock SP1.
- I installed R, wouldn't work (Restarted, same)
- LaunchPad wouldn't start (Restarted, same)
- Made sure the SQL user account was part of the R group
- LauchPad would start but R wouldn't work. (Restarted, same)
- Updated to SP2 (Restarted)
- R worked.
- Updated to SP2 CU4 (Restarted)
- R worked.

**My testing script**

```
    EXEC sp_execute_external_script
                      @language =N'R',
                      @script=N'OutputDataSet<-InputDataSet',
                      @input_data_1 =N'SELECT 1 AS hello'
                      WITH RESULT SETS (([Hello World] INT));
                        GO
```